# Removing density functions 'offset'

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to transform a density function (in black) to another one (in blue) in this spirit:

[image: density function (black) to another one (blue)]

local minima are linked together, to form a concave function in red. This function is then subtracted from the black function to give the blue one

The goal is to have a good estimation of "extrem" values

I would like to know possible theorical method to do this kind of tranformation.
I have been looking at [KDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) for example, where you could just keep some of individual kernels (separated enough)